# regex replacement in Idle editor

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex replace in the Idle editor.

```
('4',4,0, four),
('5',4,1, five),
('6',4,2, six),
```

I am trying to add self to four, five and six resulting in the following

```
('4',4,0, self.four),
('5',4,1, self.five),
('6',4,2, self.six),
```

I do have regular expression ticked in the replace dialog box.

I am expecting the string found in the brackets to fill in the value of $1

`(\w+\),)` will find the strings, but `self.$1` results in `('4',4,0, self.$1`
How do I get string replacement (ie $1) to work in the idle editor?

Comment: Try using `\1` instead of `$1`

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me where the reference is for Idle regex for future reference.

Comment: Sorry but I've never got a chance to use Idle, but I guess regexes supported in python should work in Idle too.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any standard with regards to back references to groups, but it feels like it is almost always either \1 or $1 to indicate the first group.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Correct.  IDLE's replace box is a GUI front end to python regex code. (Because of this question, I am thinking now about how to make this clearer.)  Other programming editors should have a similar option.  I know that Notepad++ on Windows does.  So this is about a regex mistake, relative to the python stdlib re module, not about IDLE.